# vb.net debugging price

Tags: vb.net, debugging

I'm having an issue here and cannot figure out where my code went wrong, so I decided to ask you guys. I made a vb.net
program for shipping costs, and it would calculate it based on the total price. The problem is if I enter lets say, 1000.34,
it gives me a zero as the shipping charge, when it should give me $14. I'm missing something very simple here, there is
no syntax errors.

Thank you.

```
Dim totPrice As Decimal
Dim Ship As Integer

Decimal.TryParse(txtTot.Text, totPrice)

Select Case totPrice
    Case Is <= 1.0
        Ship = 0
    Case 1 To 100
        Ship = 2
    Case 50 To 450
        Ship = 12
    Case 301 To 1000
        Ship = 14
    Case Is >= 1001
        Ship = 16
End Select

lblshi.Text = Ship.ToString("C0")
```

Comment: Aside from that there is no case for 1000.34. You seem to have some overlapping periods. What is the expected result for example 55? 2 or 12?

Answer (score 1):

1000.34 does not met any of the criteria, so it is returning the default ship value which is 0 since you did not set it.  It is greater than 1000, which is why it is not setting the ship to 14 but less than 1001 which is why it is not setting to 16.

To correct this you could up the value in the 301 to 1000 case, but you will probably still run into edge cases.  I think you might want to consider switching to If statements for this so you can do anding with the greater than.

```
If totPrice <= 1
  ' All of your other cases
Else If totPrice >301 and totPrice<1001
     'do work
Else If totPrice >= 1001

End If
```